# Remove leading zeros error

Tags: c

I am trying to remove the leading zeros of the number user enters so 000002 will turn into 2
However, I am getting an error saying Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
        char *str;
        scanf("%c", *str);   
        int n;
        if( ( n = strspn(str, "0" ) ) != 0 && str[n] != '\0' ) {
                printf("String without leading zeros is %s \n", &str[n]);
        } else { 
                printf("No leading zeros in %c \n", str);
        } 
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove * from this:

```
scanf("%c", *str);
```

and change %c to %s because you are scanning a string not character

Answer (score 2):

Change `%c` to `%s` and `*str` to `str`.

You don't need to use the `*` when scanning.

Comment: But `str` is uninitialized, so it will still crash.

Comment: I meant remove * from this scanf("%c", *str);

Comment: At what address will the character be stored?

Answer (score 2):

Besides the errors pointed out in the previous answers, scanf("%d") will take care of removing leading zeroes for you. Do the test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

And if you absolutely need a string, just convert with sprintf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[256];
    int a;
    scanf("%d", a);
    sprintf(str, "%d", a);
    puts(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @user3291093 has said, you need to change %c to %s since you are reading a string/char array and not a single character.

Also you need to `malloc` an area to store the array. For example:

```
char *str = NULL;

str = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
scanf("%s", str);
```

Comment: Or declare str statically as an array char str[size];

Answer (score 0):

The compiler should have warned about this problem.  *Insure warnings are enabled.*

```
char *str;
scanf("%c", *str);  // "%c" does not match `*str` for scanf()
```

Suspect OP wanted something like

```
char str[100];
if (scanf("%99s", str) == 1) Continue_Along_the_Happy_Path();
```

An alternative `fgets()` solution.

```
char str[100];
fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
char *p = buffer;
while (*p == '0') p++;
if (p != buffer) {
  printf("String without leading zeros is %s", p);
} else { 
  printf("No leading zeros in %s", str);
}
```